# Unexpected String behaviour during printing

Tags: c

I am experiencing some unpredictable behaviour in case of strings.Here it goes :

```
 int main()
        {

          char *str = charfun();

          printf("%s",str);  // This is printing garbage values

          printf("%c%c%c%c",str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3]); /* if I am printing  
          like this it is printing the result "Helo" why is it so ?
          and str[4] is '\0' (checked its ASCII value)*/
          return 0;
        }

        char* charfun()
        {
          char a[10]="Helo";
          return a;
        }
```

EDIT -

The thing which i am concerned about is not the local address which i am returning.I know it can land me into trouble . But i want to understand the printing methodology which the two printf are following and give different results.

Comment: You didn't say what garbage values it prints. I would guess that the first 4 bytes that it prints are the same as your second printf, then it prints garbage. If that garbage it prints contains a `\r`, you won't see the first 4 bytes. Redirect it to a file and look at that ... or don't bother, because it really isn't worth pursuing ... you cannot return the address of a local variable.

Comment: P.S. 'printing the result "helo"' -- if that's really true, then only the first 3 bytes are coming out as you expect them. Actually, the first byte got lowercased. So that's not what you meant, is it? If you really want to understand what's happening, the first rule is: Be precise.

Comment: Thnx for landing me somewhat closer to the solution :) . For your first comment , first printf prints some random characters(not "Helo").That upper case thing was just a typographical error. I have edited it now. But i want to knw how exactly does printf("%s",str);
In my knowledge it takes the address , goes to that location and prints the characters until it encounters a '\0'. In our above case , str[4] is '\0'. It should have terminated there and not picked up others characters beyond that. Let me know if i am wrong .

Comment: You still have not said what garbage values it prints. And why do you think that str[4] is '\0'? str is on the stack and was set in a routine that has returned ... that means that some or all of it has likely been overwritten by the call to printf.

Comment: It is also possible that printf sometimes (say, when %s is used) saves a stack variable, overwrites it, and then restores it ... that could result in the first printf producing garbage but not the second one. Again, it isn't worth pursuing ... instead learn the lesson that you should never return the address of a local variable ... it's **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: str[4] is '\0' because i printed its ascii value that is 0 .Your last comment seems valid in this case because there is no other way it could print different result. But was i right in the fact that printf prints until it encounters '\0' ??

Comment: and yes about the garbage , it show 2 characters like filed rectangle nd then a ' " '.i am not able to redirect it to file for some reason

Answer (score 5):

It is because `a` in `charfun()` is a local array. When `charfun()` returns, `a`'s address is assigned to `str`, but the array it pointed to is already invalidated.

Comment: but then why does it show correct result when i am printing it character by character ??

Comment: @amritsingh it's undefined behaviour; it can appear to work or crash.

Comment: it works because the memory hasn't been used for something else yet. (Important word here: yet).

Comment: @seth - i should consider this as undefined behaviour of printf or pointer?/ Because if the culprit is pointer then printf should show correct result in 2nd case.

Comment: @Borg - yes i knw :) ...but then why those two printf statements are printing different results ??

Comment: @amritsingh it is the function's fault for returning a pointer to a local automatic variable.

Comment: @seth - i repeat - why printf statements are showing two different results for same variable (even when its function's fault)

Comment: @amritsingh after undefined behaviour occurs, there is no point in trying to find out _why_ something is doing something, because it can do _anything_ at _any time_, and also change what it does at any time. Also, undefined behaviour can make other unrelated parts of the program work intermittently or not at all.

Comment: @amritsingh the fact that you call a function could (and probably does) overwrite some of the memory that the array was in so that the first one works but in calling it you overwrite the memory the array was in so the second one doesn't.

Comment: we have a memory portion assigned to local variable.So if the memory was overwritten then printing it like a string or char by char should show same result. I know m stretching it a bit but this thing is really bothering me.

Comment: @amrit: `printf("%s",str)` has a different path of execution  (calls different functions inside `printf()`, uses stack differently, etc.) than `printf("%c%c%c%c",str[0],str[1],str[2],str[3])`.  Therefore it has different behavior - whether used in a well defined scenario (you're asking it to do things differently after all) and in undefined behavior scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that when you create the local variable it is allocated on the stack and is therefore unavailable once the function finishes execution. The preferable way would be to use malloc() to reserve non-local memory. the string `a` is local to the function, you can't return a pointer to it, It's an `Undefined Behavior` so it must be allocated on heap instead of stack using malloc:

```
char *charfun(){
    char *a = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    strcpy(a,"Helo");
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I am allocating it to stack just to understand its behaviour.It will work fine on heap ofcourse. The thing which creates confusion to me is the two different results of printf statement on printing values present at same memory location.

Comment: @amritsingh: To you it's confusing, but in reality it's undefined. `printf` can format your hard drive at this point if it wants to.

Comment: @netcoder printf can always format your hard drive if it wants to ... it just won't be a conforming implementation. I was a member of the C Standards committee and I always wince at this nonsensical misunderstanding of the concepts that we tried to formalize.